# How to publish built-in app in RemoteApp?

Tags: remoteapp

I'm trying to publish a built in app from Microsoft store through RemoteApp.

What I did is creating a .bat file with this command:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e,/root,shell:appsFolder\FortinetInc.FortiTokenWindows_sq9g7krz3c65j!App
```

When running the bat file locally on the session host, the app opens fine, but when publishing the bat file to RemoteApp Programs, only the explorer.exe is opening and not the application.

how I can go around this?